# How to control indeterminante ProgressBar which is not part of a ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

There is , indeterminate `progressBar` which rotates until `ListView` content is ready to be shown. Both `progressBar` and the `listView` are part of the same `Fragment`.

So I coded that this `progressBar` is made Visisble and Gone from the `AsyncTask` that fetches the content.

```
mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
mProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable()
            .setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.pink), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

new MyAsyncTask().execute();

//then in asynctask
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, MyAdapter> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected MyAdapter doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //do the stuff and return loaded adapter

        return adapter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(MyAdapter adapter) {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

However the `progressBar` **is frozen and does not spin**?!

I tried instantiating the `progressBar` from `onPreExecute`, but the outer `progressBar` does not accept the parameteres I set inside `AsyncTask`. I can see that because it appears with default color instead with the custom.

So how can I control this `progressBar`? Right now all I need is to show it when the content starts loading, and to hide it when it's ready to be shown.

**NOTE:** I don't need a `progressBar` inside each item, but I need it the way I described.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried make a constructor for MyAsyncTask and give it the progressBar as a parameter?

You can save private attributes inside like in any other Java class.

EDIT: I would define a custom handler and call it from the activity, playing with the visibility of the progressBar.

```
public final class LoadingDialogHandler extends Handler {
    private final WeakReference<Activity> mActivity;
    // Constants for Hiding/Showing Loading dialog
    public static final int HIDE_LOADING_DIALOG = 0;
    public static final int SHOW_LOADING_DIALOG = 1;

    private View mLoadingDialogContainer;

    public LoadingDialogHandler(Activity activity, View container) {
        mActivity = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
        mLoadingDialogContainer = container;
    }

    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Activity activity = mActivity.get();
        if (activity == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (msg.what == SHOW_LOADING_DIALOG) {
            mLoadingDialogContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else if (msg.what == HIDE_LOADING_DIALOG) {
            mLoadingDialogContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

}

And call it like this:

In your activity/fragment declare the handle an associate the progress bar:

```
LoadingDialogHandler loadingDialogHandler = new LoadingDialogHandler(yourActivity, findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator));
```

To show/hide (sample of showing):

```
loadingDialogHandler.sendEmptyMessage(LoadingDialogHandler.SHOW);
```

PS: Maybe you have to run it in UIthread like this:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //update progressBar
                }
            });
```

Comment: I did it. But the `ProgressBar` still does not spin. Seems like frozen. There is not updating progress bar. It's indeterminate progress bar.

Comment: I've edited my answer, I hope this could help you now ;)

Comment: Good idea which I will use in another project, but the ProgressBAr is still frozen.

Comment: I don't know if you have already done this, but try removing mProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable()
            .setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.pink), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

If it still does not work, remove the call to setColorFilter. If not, change PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY to Mode.MULTIPLY only. This is what I would do but I'm not sure about what is happening here.

Comment: That line simply changes the color of the progress bar. The issue is not there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

that's it's so simple, there's a builtin API for that function:

```
mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
listView.setEmptyView(mProgressBar);
```

done! The listView will automatically call setVisibility with GONE and VISIBLE when the list is empty or not

Comment: This does not work when adapter is loading. Only in case adapter is empty or null.

Comment: But when it's loading the adapter is empty, also you can set the adapter to the list only after it completed loading.